# Wait for class to load value after clicking button selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

After the website is loaded I click a button successfully which will then generate some numbers in this class

```
<div class="styles__Value-sc-1bfbyy7-2 eVmhyz"></div>
```

but not instantly, it will put them in one by one. Selenium will instantly grab the first value that gets put into the class but doesn't wait for the other values to get added. Any way to wait for it to load all the values in there before grabbing it.

Here is the python code I use for grabbing the value:

```
total = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='styles__Value-sc-1bfbyy7-2 eVmhyz']").text
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has a `WebDriverWait` method:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
delay = 5
total = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(<locator>)
```

I haven't tested it locally but it may work. There is also `presence_of_all_elements_located` method, you can find the details on [this](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html) page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't get it to work with what you are suggesting unfortunately, currently will just use the time.sleep(2) although that doesn't really look good. I did this: `total = WebDriverWait(browser,delay).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located("//div[@class='styles__Value-sc-1bfbyy7-2 eVmhyz']")).text` Not sure if it is correct.

Comment: I think you can just use `WebDriverWait` too. It will probably act like `time.sleep` but probably a more selenium way of doing it but yeah whatever works! Sorry that it wasn't too much help

Comment: So `<div class="styles__Value-sc-1bfbyy7-2 eVmhyz"></div>` class stays the same and numbers put in it right? If that's the case I don't think what I suggested will be the best way. Maybe if you know how many numbers will be generated in that class you can do a while loop and wait until the numbers generated reaches a certain threshold.

Comment: Yeah class stays the same, I'll just work with sleep for now until I get this running. I'll try to make it better later. Thanks for trying to help though!